# Plain Button With Padding

Tags: css, button, whitespace, padding

The following CSS apparently results in the following Button. As you can see there is a weird gray plain button within the white padding. How do I fix this?

How do I make the gray go away?

```
.button_style {
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
}
```

[image]

NOTE: The green space is the background, the white space and gray space are both clickable button.

Comment: Can you show your HTML? I am guessing from how it looks that you are wrapping your button in a outer element and styling the outer element. But you can style the button directly. Then your background color will override the gray of the button. **Edit**: actually in that case it wouldn't be clickable. Just show your html so we can help.

Comment: be sure to make the background-color for the parent not for text :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I had previously, which was giving me the plain gray button:

```
<p><span class="button_style"><a href="example.com">Website</a></span> </p>
```

I changed it to the following, which resolved my problem:

```
<input class="button_style" type="button" onclick="location.href = 'http://www.botequotes.com';" value="Visit Site" />
```

NOTE: JavaScript must be enabled in order to use 'onclick="location.href'

Answer (score 0):

Use border: 0 or border: none to remove that. By the way, what browser are you using?

HTML

```
<button class="button_style">hello</button>
```

CSS

```
.button_style {
   border: 0;
   background-color: white;
   padding: 15px 15px;
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
   font-size: 16px;
   margin: 4px 2px;
}
```